# wgs84 of GeoJson downloaded from Mapbox

Tags: geojson, mapbox, wgs84

What's the WGS84 of the GeoJSON that I download from Mapbox website. I tried to add some geometry created in mapbox to my postgis and I need to keep coordinates consistent.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? WGS84 is a datum: it means that the GeoJSON file is in EPSG:4326 and stores latitude and longitude.

Comment: I created PostGIS database for Geodjango. So default SRID is 4326 (EPSG:4326).  I will export a polynomial from Mapbox in GeoJSON format, which I will insert to the databse. what SRID does GeoJSON standard use? is certain SRID part of the GEoJSON standard, like WGS84/EPSG:4326? I'm new to this gis thing, I'm still learning concepts etc; sorry for my ignorance and thanks for help